# White, read-only Text field in SWT

Tags: java, swt, readonly

I'm trying to make a large white box in an SWT window to display information. I want this to look different from a label but I also want it to be non-editable.

So far I've only been able to create a noon-editable text box with a grey back (top). I'm aiming for the look I get with a `List` (under the `Text`).

[image]

(The problem with `List` is that it can only display text on one line per list item. I need to display perhaps a paragraph of text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really **have to** use a white background, you can use a normal `Text` and just prevent editing it.

**However**, as already mentioned by @Eugene, you should stick to UI conventions, because doing otherwise might confuse users...

Here is some code that creates a read-only `Text` with "normal" background:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setText("Read only");

    text.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            e.doit = false;
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(600, 60);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also catch keyboard events and block them.

```
txtField.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {
        e.doit = false;
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass SWT.READ_ONLY to your text field constructor.

Comment: I did that, but that makes the Text field look grey (as shown above) and also only applies the surrounding box immediately around the text. I want it to stretch it the whole width of the parent composite (as shown with list)

Comment: Graying out helps the user see that it is futile to edit the contents. Generally, I would suggest following the OS UI conventions. The control size is governed by the layout so you can make it as big as you want. Can you list the source code in your question?